# How to interleave arrays of real and complex numbers to use vDSP_ctoz?

Tags: ios, swift

The swift syntax changed over the years and this code that was working perfecly is not anymore...

```
var zerosR = [Float](count: windowSizeOverTwo, repeatedValue: 0.0)
var zerosI = [Float](count: windowSizeOverTwo, repeatedValue: 0.0)
var cplxData = DSPSplitComplex( realp: &zerosR, imagp: &zerosI )

let xAsComplex = UnsafePointer<DSPComplex>( inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress } )
vDSP_ctoz( xAsComplex, 2, &cplxData, 1, vDSP_Length(windowSizeOverTwo) )

vDSP_fft_zrip( setup, &cplxData, 1, log2n, FFTDirection(kFFTDirection_Forward) )
```

Every line of this code shows an error under Swift 4

I was able to convert everything except for this line

```
let xAsComplex = UnsafePointer<DSPComplex>( inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress } )
```

that does not compile with this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer?' to expected
>   argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>?'

Comment: What is `inputSignal` ?

Comment: `inputSignal` is an array of Floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer to the storage of `Float` elements in the `inputSignal` array must be *rebound* to point to an array of `DSPComplex` values:

```
let inputSignal: [Float] = ...

inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    floatPtr in
    floatPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self) {
        cmplxPtr in
        vDSP_ctoz(cmplxPtr.baseAddress!, 2, &cplxData, 1, vDSP_Length(windowSizeOverTwo) )
    }
}
```

See also [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html) for more information.

Note that those pointers are only valid during the execution of the closure, and must not be passed to the outside. What you did in

```
let xAsComplex = UnsafePointer<DSPComplex>( inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress } )
```

was actually relying on undefined behavior.